# Forbid mocking methods that are undefined on original object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking

I want to ensure that my `EventNotifier` object catches and logs an exception to the Rails logger, so I writed the following rspec test using rspec-mocks:

```
describe EventNotifier do
  before(:all) do
    RSpec::Mocks::setup(self)
  end

  it 'logs exception on error' do
    error = RuntimeError.new('simulated for tests')

    EventDispatcher.should_receive(:dispatch).with('a message').and_raise(error)
    Rails.logger.should_receive(:warning).with(error)

    subject.notify('a message')
  end
end

class EventDispatcher
  def dispatch(message)
    # stuff
  end
end

class EventNotifier
  def notify(message)
    EventDispatcher.dispatch(message)
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    Rails.logger.warning(e)
  end
end
```

The test passes with bells and whistles, but I did a *big* mistake. Can you spot it? Indeed, the Rails method to log a warning is `warn`, not `warning`. So this code will fail when used for real.

Is there a way to make rspec-mock forbid mocking methods that do not exist on the original object?

Another example where it can be useful: if I decide to rename `EventDispatcher#dispatch` as `EventDispatcher#route`, then the test still passes. If it was java, it would have failed at compilation because the interface has changed. With rspec-mock, I do not know how to make it fail automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be possible with rspec-mocks 3.0 which introduces [verifying doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles):

> Verifying doubles are a stricter alternative to normal doubles that provide
>   guarantees about what is being verified. **When using verifying doubles, RSpec
>   will check that the methods being stubbed are actually present on the
>   underlying object if it is available**. Prefer using verifying doubles over
>   normal doubles.

So given these classes (examples taken from the [spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double)):

```
class ConsoleNotifier
  def notify(msg)
    puts message
  end
end

class User < Struct.new(:notifier)
  def suspend!
    notifier.notify("suspended as")
  end
end
```

This example would pass because the method `notify` exists for a real `ConsoleNotifier` instance:

```
describe User, '#suspend!' do
  it 'notifies the console' do
    notifier = instance_double("ConsoleNotifier")

    expect(notifier).to receive(:notify).with("suspended as")

    user = User.new(notifier)
    user.suspend!
  end
end
```

If the `notify` method is renamed as `publish`, the example would fail because expectations are on the method `notify` and that method does not exist on target object.

```
# would make example fail
class ConsoleNotifier
  def publish(msg)
    puts message
  end
end
```

If we add a `color` argument to the `notify` method, it will fail too because the method arity is incorrect in the expectation (wrong number of arguments).

```
class ConsoleNotifier
  def notify(msg, color)
    puts color + message
  end
end
```

When putting expectations on class, like `EventDispatcher.should_receive(:dispatch)` or `expect(EventDispatcher).to receive(:dispatch)`, the created double is named a [partial double](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#test-specific-extension) in rspec-mocks vocabulary.

To make partial doubles act like verifying doubles, the `verify_partial_doubles` configuration option must be set:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

And it will automagically ensure that the `EventDispatcher` class has a `dispatch` method. So if this method is renamed, the test will fail, as expected!